# Fixed header above scrollable table

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to have a table header, in a seperate div stay in place while a div undernearth is able to scroll al arge list of records. Both divs are in a div named Layer 3. Hereis the css file I am using:

```css
#Layer3
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 89%;
    height: 40%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 56%;
    background-color: #f1ffff;
}

#Layer3 h1 {
    font-size: medium;
    color: #000033;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.tableheader {
}

.tablecontent {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and part of the php code I am using to generate the html:

```
echo '<div id="tableheader" class="tableheader">';

echo "<h1>{$query} Auctions</h1>" . "\n"; 
echo "</div>";
echo '<div id="tablecontent" class="tablecontent">';

echo "<table border='0' width='100%'><tr>" . "\n"; 

echo "<td width='15%'>Seller ID</td>" . "\n";
echo "<td width='10%'>Start Date</td>" . "\n";
echo "<td width='75%'>Description</td>" . "\n";

echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $pk = $row['ARTICLE_NO'];
    echo '<tr>' . "\n"; 

    // table contens generated in here

    echo '</tr>' . "\n"; 
}
}

echo "</div>";
```

I am not sure what I have missed, but tableheader does not seem to be stationary, or even separate from tablecontent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div name does not equal div id.  #Layer3 is referencing an element with an id of Layer3.  Only one element is allowed to have a given id; all ids must be unique.

Don't forget to close your tags (table).

If div#Layer3 is scrolling everything inside it then it has some overflow set.  Redefine it to overflow:hidden in the #Layer3 style.  You may need to try playing with margins and floats to get things positioned right, but ill leave that to you.

Comment: I have speicified overflow:auto and it is generating a scrollbar even though I have not specified the height, but the table header is scrolling with it, something I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to close the `<table>` tag after your main foreach() loop.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to pear down your problem to just the bare elements you're interested in.  In particular, I'll get rid of all the `<div>` nodes.  Here's your very basic table:

```
<table>
   <thead class="tableheader">
      <tr>
         <th>Seller ID</th>
         <th>Start Date</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="scrolling">
      <tr>
         <td>28</td><td>25 January 2009</td><td>Hello World!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> etc. </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

(Notice the use of the `<thead>` element.)

Now here's the style sheet that will produce the scrolling you want:

```css
.tableheader {
    display: block;
}

.scrolling {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

th, td { /* first column */
    width: 200px
}

th + th, td + td { /* second column */
    width: 240px
}

th + th + th, td + td + td { /* third column */
    width: 316px
}
```

Notice that a consequence of setting `display:block` is that you have to fix the width of columns...